# Laravel 5.3 groupBy() Broken?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The following query works in Laravel 5.2 but not in Laravel 5.3.

```
$messages = Message::with('sender.profile', 'recipient.profile')
    ->where('sender_id', 1)
    ->orWhere('recipient_id', 1)
    ->groupBy('thread')
    ->get();
```

When run in 5.3 I receive the following error message

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
'tmp_laravel.messages.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `messages` 
where `sender_id` = 1 or `recipient_id` = 1 group by `thread`)
```

Now, before you say it's a database issue, remember: this same query works in Laravel 5.2 on the **same** database. So if it was my version of MariaDB acting up it certainly shouldn't work in L5.2, right?

Plus, if I run the query directly in Sequel Pro it works.

In fact, just to be sure it wasn't something I did when upgrading my app I installed two fresh copies of Laravel: 5.2 and 5.3. and installed the exact same code in each so that they would be identical as far as controllers, models, routes, .env, etc., then ran the query again in each version. Same results: works in L5.2 and breaks in L5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select * from `messages` 
where `sender_id` = 1
   or `recipient_id` = 1 
group by `thread`
```

This query is not valid but "works" in MySQL/MariaDB with strict mode disabled. Laravel doesn't use the servers default settings. You need to modify your `config/database.php` and set

```
'strict' => false,
```

in the MySQL settings.

However you should consider to rewrite that query to explicitly select first/last message per thread.

Comment: I'll take your advice and figure out a new query. Thanks!

Comment: what would you recommend as a rewrite?

Comment: @timgavin - write a new question. This one is about strict mode and settings. There are many answered questions on SO like "How to select latest/oldest entry per group?" for MySQL. But yet i haven't seen a laravel solution. If you post a link to the new question here, i'll have a look at it later.